# How to pass in a C++ function pointer (of non-static member function) to a pre-defined C Function?

Tags: c++, c, templates, function-pointers

I am looking at using library from http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/, which is written in C.

However I am including it inside a member function "dlevmar_der" which is expecting two function pointers as its argument:

```
int dlevmar_der(
    void (*func)(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata), 
    void (*jacf)(double *p, double *j, int m, int n, void *adata),  
    double *p,         /* I/O: initial parameter estimates. On output contains the estimated solution */
    double *x,         /* I: measurement vector. NULL implies a zero vector */
    int m,             /* I: parameter vector dimension (i.e. #unknowns) */
    int n,             /* I: measurement vector dimension */
    int itmax,         /* I: maximum number of iterations */
    double opts[4],
    double info[LM_INFO_SZ],
    double *work,
    double *covar,
    void *adata
)
```

I have following simplified template class with two non-static member function CallBack and MyJac. (assuming I have all other attributes m_solution, m_info etc in the class as well):

```
Template<class F> 
class MyClass
{
    public: 
        typedef void (MyClass<F>::*FuncPtrType)(float*);

        void Start()
        {
            this->Run(&MyClass<F>::MyJac);
        }

    protected:
        void Callback(ValueType x[], ValueType result[], int m, int n, void* adata){ // some code }
        void MyJac(ValueType x[], ValueType result[], int m, int n, void* adata){ // some code }

        void Run(FuncPtrType func)
        {
             int iterCount = dlevmar_der(&MyClass<F>::Callback, func,
        (double*)&this->m_solution[0],
        (double*)&zero[0],
        this->m_function.NumberOfParameters,
        this->m_function.NumberOfFunctionValues,
        this->m_maxIterations,
        this->m_options,
        this->m_info,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        static_cast<void*>(this));
        }
}
```

However I am getting an error inside the "Run" function when calling the `Start()` function, saying: `error C2664: 'slevmar_der' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall MyClass<F>::* )(float *,float *,int,int,void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(float *,float *,int,int,void *)`

My questions is whether the `dlevmar_der` function can only take function pointer to a static member function? or is there any ways I can use non-static member function with `dlevmar_der` implementation?

Comment: Yes, a pointer to (non-static) member function cannot be used where a free (non-member) or static member function is expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build a trampoline function.

Just pass `this` as the `adata` parameter and the write a callback function that casts back `adata` to a proper typed pointer and calls the method. For example:

```
  void myFunc(double *p, double *hx, int m, int n, void *adata) {
      MyClass *self = static_cast<MyClass>(adata);
      self->funcMethod(p, hx, m, n, self->func_adata);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a static wrapper

```
template<class F> 
class MyClass
{
    protected:
        void Callback(ValueType x[], ValueType result[], int m, int n) { 

        }

        static void CallbackWrapper(
              ValueType x[], ValueType result[], int m, int n, 
              void* adata) 
        { 
            static_cast<MyClass<T>*>(adata)->Callback(x, result, m, n);
        }

        void Run(FuncPtrType func)
        {
             int iterCount = dlevmar_der(
                 &MyClass<F>::CallbackWrapper, /*..*/ );
        }
};
```

Comment: static function don't have a `this`. you probably meant `adata`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ member function pointers cannot be used interchangeably with regular function pointers.

However, you can usually safely use a **static** member function pointer where a C function pointer is expected. Your C API looks like it allows you to pass your own `void*` context parameter to the callback. You can use this to pass your instance pointer back to a static method, and use that to call your isntance method, like so:

```
static void StaticCallback(/* Args... */, void *user_data)
{
    MyClass *ptr = static_cast<MyClass*>(user_data);
    ptr->NonStaticCallback(/*args...*/);
}
```

(Strictly speaking, you need to use a free (non-member) function declared `extern "C"` to do the forwarding, but a static method is generally fine.)